# Число существительного

Tags: грамматика

Помогите, пожалуйста, затрудняюсь... "Пути формирования и развития читательской грамотности на разных этапах уроков (или урока) русского языка и литературы". Необходимо обосновать.

Comment: Урок — смешной модуль. Как минимум курс с названием «Уроки РЯ». (На разных этапах или образования,  или обучения, или просвещения.)

Comment: на разных этапах преподавания (уроков) РЯиЛ, на разных этапах курса (уроков) РЯиЛ,...

Answer (score 1):

Елена, а Вы прочтите предложение ещё раз - оно содержит ответ. Поиск путей формирования и развития читательской грамотности на разных этапах...

В один урок никак не уместится. Невольно напрашивается множественное число - из-за неисчерпаемости темы.

(Меня смущают только "разные этапы уроков" - чуть коробит мою читательскую грамотность.)